# storybook: use awesome-typescript-loader

Tags: settings, storybook, babel-loader, awesome-typescript-loader

By default Storybook uses `babel-loader`, but the current version of babel-loader is incompatible to the one Storybook requires. So I decided to use `awesome-typescript-loader` instead. That is, my project uses `babel-loader` and Storybook uses `awesome-typescript-loader`.

I added the `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = ({ config }) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader'),
      },
    ],
  });
  config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');
  return config;
};
```

but Storybook still insist to load `babel-loader`.

```
ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'babel-loader'
```

How can I set up an alternative loader?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `@next` version, there was [a fix 5 days ago](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/13220) that solves it by skipping babel loader check.

This is how to run the init command with the `@next` version:

```
npx -p @storybook/cli@next sb init
```

Additionally, if you haven't already, clean up `babel-loader` from `package.json`, remove npm lock file, and re-run npm install.

Be aware @next is not the stable version, and this is not completely ideal, but if you are interested keep following [the conversation](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/4764)